# Why some people are born gay ? Is it a punishment of some bad karma in past life?

Tags: karma, homosexuality

Considering the societal and other issues faced by Gay men, is one born so because they did some bad karma in previous life ?

Comment: You can use the term "homosexual" rather than gay

Comment: yes. my guess it is a consequence of the proliferation of visual pornography, those who participate and normalize it and the resultant samskaras it leaves on one's mind at the time of death. in the past one would not even look at one's own wife/husband naked, sex used to happen in a dark room under covers. nowadays as even public movies show nudity of both men and women, and the visual medium leaves much stronger impressions in subconscious than touch alone, one can get combined/mixed feelings about which gender one is attracted to. so they get a man's body but a woman's mind in the next birth

Comment: or vice-versa. same with people on the trans/bi/queer spectrum. if they treat this birth as a punishment and ride out that janma, their sentence might be over. but if they double down, and indulge in the sensual homosexual activity, they're digging their grave deeper. P.S: I don't have any shastras to back up this opinion. Probably because Shastras were smart enough to only write rules to and about people who had inclination in following them.